# How to intercept the request handler in ASP.NET with the same thread by which the handler is executed?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, servlet-filters, interceptor

I am looking for a hook which intercepts the execution of request handlers, which will be executed by the same thread as the request handler.

I know that ASP.NET uses events for such purposes, but the events directly before and after the execution of the request handler (PreRequestHandlerExecute, PostRequestHandlerExecute) are not guaranteed to be executed by the same thread, especially when using ajax.

In Java there are ServletFilter which serve these purposes, is there something similar in ASP.NET?

Comment: Why do you need to execute on the same thread?

Comment: We have (very stateful) Java beans in the background and I want to synchronize the access to them. Synchronizing only works if locking and unlocking is done by the very same thread.